# Watching new entries on Linux Syslog from a C program

Tags: c, linux, syslog, ppp

I want to write a program that monitors syslog and performs an action when PPP authentication fails.

I think "tail -f /var/log/syslog" could help, but I'm not sure how to use it... probably using pipes?

I have found something similar written in bash, but I'm not sure how to implement it in C.

This is the bash method:

First create a named pipe using mkfifo:

```
$ mkfifo -p /home/mezgani/syslog.pipe
```

Make syslog.conf to points to this file:

```
*.info |/home/mezgani/syslog.pipe
```

Restart syslog:

```
$ sudo pkill -HUP syslogd
```

Create processing script that read the pipe

```
$ cat > foo
#!/bin/bash
cat /home/mezgani/syslog.pipe | while read input
do
    # some stuff
    echo ${input}
    # ….
done
```

Comment: Sounds very hacky. Isn't there a PPP plugin mechanism you can use instead?

Comment: I did some research on linux PPP server but couldn't find anything.

Comment: @trojanfoe The `pppd man page` mentions a few scripts that are run at various stages of connection build-up and tear-down. Perhaps one could hook up to that? But it may be more difficult than simply monitoring the syslog: Perhaps one needs a simple a state machine detecting when an established connection is torn down without successful authentication, or such.

Comment: By the way, are you watching client connection attempts on a server, or are you trying to connect as a client/user? IIUC, pppd is running on both sides of a connection. On the client side, an exit code of 20 indicates authentication failure.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I think you meant to tag the OP instead of me?

Comment: @trojanfoe Both. You were wondering about a plugin mechanism, and yes, there is *something* (no idea whether it is really suitable). The OP gets pinged anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I could found the solution!!

The solution was using named pipes!

First, I need to create a named pipe:
**mkfifo /pipe**

Then, I feed the pipe with the log info:
**tail -f /var/log/syslog > /pipe**

And then, I read the pipe from the C program using OPEN

```
int pipefd;
pipefd = open("/tmp/myFIFO", O_WRONLY);
```

Comment: You still need to be root to read /var/log/syslog. I suppose one could also write a C file that opens /var/log/syslog for reading directly and then emulates `tail -f `? No pipe, no shell setup.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use inotify function. Using it you can monitor if a file or directory has changed.